# Passing Kendo Grid request from javascript to mvc controller method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to pass filters of kendogrid to mvc controller, but something is going wrong. I tried the way in this [link](http://blog.codebeastie.com/kendo-grid-passing-datasourcerequest-from-your-own-javascript/).

This is javascript side:

```
var grid = $(gridId).data("kendoGrid"),
    remote = '...',
    parameterMap = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap,
    requestObj = {
            sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
            filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
    },
    postData = parameterMap(requestObj),
    success = function(){...};

    $.post(remote, postData, success);
```

This is controller side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSumOfInvoiceAmount([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request){...}
```

Although there is some filter in kendo grid, it seems as no filter in controller method. What is wrong here ?

Comment: Did you receive any data from AJAX request in controller action and already checked possible errors in both server & client sides?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes I receive request data having filter object with no data. I don't see any error in javascript or serverside.

Comment: @serefbilge Have you set server side filter property ?

Comment: @AGH the filter property exists in DataSourceRequest object at serverside.

Comment: @serefbilge I asked about on grid during configuration.